# Probability of $P(X>Y)=p_1, P(Y>Z) = p_2, P(Z>X) =p_3$, find minimum of $p_1 +p_2 +p_3$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$X,Y$ and $Z$ are $3$ random variables equalling numbers and a probability is defined such that:

$P(X>Y)=p_1,\, P(Y>Z) = p_2, \,P(Z>X) =p_3$

a) thus find maximum of $p_1 +p_2 +p_3$

b) what is the maximum that minimum value of $p_1,p_2$ and $p_3$ may take?

Hint is provided as: consider set theory operation.

*My thinking process* - let us define the events  $X>Y =A$, $Y>Z  =B$, $Z>X =C$.

Now $P(A \cup B \cup C) = p_1 + p_2 + p_3 -p_1p_2 -p_2p_3 -p_3p_1 + 0$,

now $P(A \cup B \cup C)$ is at most $1$ therefore I have the inequality $p_1 + p_2 + p_3 \leq p_1p_2 +p_2p_3 +p_3p_1 + 1$.

I don't know how to proceed further! Maybe some geometric figures, etc!

Thanks!

Comment: I think something missed.

Comment: This is the complete problem !

Comment: I put down my thought process now.What exactly do you think was missed ?

Comment: Subject line asks about minimum of $p_1 + p_2 + p_3$, part a) in the body asks to "find maximum" of this sum, and part b) asks "what is the maximum that minimum value of $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$ may take.  It seems to me the subject line is not consistent with either of the questions posed in the body text.

Answer (score 1):

> Draw Venn diagrams!

Let $F=[X\gt Y\gt Z]$, $G=[Y\gt Z\gt X]$ and $H=[Z\gt X\gt Y]$. Assume that $F\cup G\cup H$ is a partition of $\Omega$. Then $p_1+p_2+p_3=2$. This is the maximal valuee.

In every case, $p_1+p_2+p_3\leqslant2$ hence $\min\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}\leqslant\frac23$. This value is achieved when $P[F]=P[G]=P[H]=\frac13$ hence $\frac23$ is the optimal value.

Comment: I didnt get how p1+p2+p3=2

Comment: Did you draw a Venn diagram? Please name every region in it so that we can be specific.

Comment: I tried , not so good at venn/ geometric  interpretation.. could you post the solved case ?

Comment: In other words, you (very politely) refuse to move even your little finger in the direction I suggested and ask instead for a complete solution ready to be handed back to your teacher. Nice.